# How to change background color for TextView dynamicaly

Tags: android, textview

Here is my code:

drawable\textview_rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="20dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#667162" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

templatesgrid_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TemplateName_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_rounded"
        android:text="Template">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How i'm trying to change color

private class TemplatesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public TemplatesAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.templatesgrid_item, mTemplates);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Templates vTemplate = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.templatesgrid_item, null);
    }

    TextView vTemplateItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TemplateName_txt);
    vTemplateItem.setText(String.valueOf(vTemplate.getName()));
    vTemplateItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & Math.abs(vTemplate.getColor())))));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

So my problem is next, when i'm dynamicaly changing TextView color using setBackgroundColor(), the TextView lost shape settings. Can somebody explain how to dynamicaly change TextView color and store shape settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Drawable.setColorFilter()` to color the shape:

```
vTemplateItem.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: You are the man!))) Thank you, your solution really easy and works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the full function for changing background color?!
And What's 'some color'?!

Please try this code to solve the problem :

`TextView mTextView = new TextView(activity);
mTextView.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
mTextView.setText("My Text");`

Comment: Your solution also change color, but shape settings is lost. I have added full function text, i'm reading colors for each item from database

Answer (score 0):

You should take the drawable from your view and change its color depending on of which type it is. The code would be similar to this:

```
Drawable background = textView.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
    ((ShapeDrawable) background).getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
    ((GradientDrawable) background).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code ?

**Edit 1:**

```
LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable)mTextView.getBackground();
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable)   bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape_id);
shape.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello. Thank's for answer. I have tried but catch exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable